# How to reboot on 1st time/fresh install (not on upgrade) and that to without using custom actions?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, registry

I am trying to build a WIX installer MSI Package. While installation process I am doing some registry entries which needs reboot to take effect..

Well my question is,

How to reboot on 1st time/fresh install (not on upgrade) and that to without using custom actions? (custom actions are restricted by several AntiVirus programs, well that's another story)

I have tried ScheduleReboot After='InstallFinalize' with several conditions like : 
NOT REINSTALL, REMOVE="ALL", NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE, NOT INSTALLED.. but still it's rebooting always, And I also have checked that if I remove

Thanks

NileshV

Comment: What does no success mean?  Is it always rebooting or never rebooting?  Do you have the REBOOT property defined in your installer?

Comment: I have wrote code : 
<ScheduleReboot Before='InstallFinalize'>
 // tried several conditions here
</ScheduleReboot>

and its Always rebooting on fresh install as well as upgrade

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Windows wants to reboot anyway - if that's needed it will happen, so you first need to be sure that it is not rebooting by skipping the ScheduleReboot completely. As Chroistopher points out, if you're not setting the REBOOT property then Windows will reboot you anyway.

The condition you want is Not Installed. Unfortunately property names are case sensitive and your spelling of INSTALLED is wrong.

Comment: Yhh I have checked that if I remove <ScheduleReboot..  It will not reboot.